# Unable to load css for views in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc

I'm learning asp.net and using mvc as a starting point. I've got the app running however when trying to add CSS to a particular view it doesn't do anything. I've seen many solutions but not seem to work for me. Plugging css selector directly in _Layout works only for the main page but doesnt for independent views

- Refresh cache
- @Styles.Render("~/Content/styles.css") add to view
- link css in head of _Layout

I am obviously missing something; can someone figure out what I am doing wrong and explain why it works?

Folder structure:

[image]

_Layout.cshtml head

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - bugtracker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/bugtracker.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link href="~/Content/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<bugtracker.Models.Issue>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <span class="cardborder">
        <p> ID: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id) </p>
        <p> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name) </p>
        <p> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description) </p>
        <p> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Type) </p>
        <p> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Priority) </p>
    </span>
}
```

Content/css/styles.css

```
.cardborder{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: can you check in browser dev tools if the css is loaded when navigating to index.cshtml?

Comment: @gsharp When I go to sources it shows 'Failed to load resource for styles.css status of 404' and the styles.css in Content/css is blank using inspect tool

Comment: It seems to be the link path that is the issue, using ```~/css/styles.css``` works if I have it under wwwroot folder but I want to use it from the Content folder

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'd also try to load the script at the bottom of the _Layout.cshtml to see if that changes behavior,  also make sure to have caching turned off in your browser.[image]

Comment: At the end of the _Layout.cshtml there are already scripts there from when it was created via command line (bootstrap.bundle.min.js, jquery.min.js) if thats what you mean